# How to include external JavaScript in place?

Tags: craft3, templating, javascript

We include an external script from a vendor and the URL doesn't end in .js. It returns JavaScript that creates a widget in place. I was able to fake it out by adding a '&js=.js' parameter but it still rendered with the other scripts.

Is there an option for {% js %} to render in place? A {% js at right-here %}?

Comment: I may be missing something here, but you probably just want to use the `<script>` tag?

Comment: I may be too. That's the only thing I've got working so far, but I'm not sure if there's a standard way to do it.

Comment: The {% js %} tag can only inject javascript at the end or beginning of the page so it's fine to use the <script> tag if you need something in place.

Answer (score 1):

In your template you can use the `<script src="">` tag as it's a combination of the html and twig. So it will load your external javascript files.

Also you can use the inline javascript or javascript file using this tag `{% js %}` like below.

```
{# Use for JS file #}
{% js "/assets/js/script.js" %}

{# Use as a JS code block #}
{% js %}

console.log("hello World");    

{% endjs %}
```

Comment: Inside a {% js %} block, could you pull in an external script and run it?